# Jenkins Branch Specifier Not Being Obeyed

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have a Jenkins build configured to pull from a Gitlab repo.

I have specified in the build config, branch specifier to only pull from one specific branch:

```
Branch Specifier (blank for 'any'): origin/development
```

Yet regardless of which branch a commit is pushed to, the build still triggers and pulls the committed branch and builds it.

Am I misunderstanding exactly what the branch specifier is supposed to do? I want to only build when a certain branch is committed to.

I've also tried the following branch specifiers with the same results:

```
development
*/development
refs/head/development
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue (sort of).

Under the **Build Triggers** option, I specified to only match certain branches.

`Filter Branch By Regex: development`

Comment: Thanks for bringing the solution, but, it means that whenever it comes to gitlab, the "Branch Specifier" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Same, whatever I put in "branch specifier" : master. But push on every Git branches still to trigger a build. (And the worst thing is that it don't only build sources from master).

Under "Comment for triggering a build" -> button advanced :
"Filter branches by name" : I wrote "master" and saved.

Now only push on master trigger a build.