# Build branch with specific string in its name

Tags: git, jenkins, github, wildcard

I'm configuring my **Jenkins** job to build only branches that contain the string `4prod` in its name, e.g :

```
origin/4prod/utility
origin/sbt/utility-4prod
```

and skip other branches.

I've tried many wildcards/regex combinations in the branch specifier but without success :

```
refs/head/**4prod** , origin/**4prod** , **4prod** , .*4prod.* ...
```

The problem is whenever I push changes to Github, the job gets triggered even if changes are pushed to another branch, other than `**4prod**` branches.

It looks like the branch specifier is not working properly - is there any solution to that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38426243/1713298

Comment: This option is specific to gitlab plugin

Comment: Try `:^.*4prod.*$` (regex needs the colon prefix)

Comment: @Vasan tried it without success

Comment: @josephino Strange, that should've worked. How about just `:4prod`? Or `:.*4prod.*`? Also make sure you've removed any other expressions except this one from the box.

Comment: @Vasan with ":prod" no build was triggered after a push, with ":.*4prod.*" build is triggered even if changes was pushed to other branches

Comment: @josephino Interesting. I guess it does a partial match then, and also its `*` operator must be greedy. Make sure with `:4prod` it _does_ trigger a build if you commit to a branch with `4prod` in it. If it triggers properly, that's your solution